# String Array to JSON String

Tags: code-golf, string, array, json

## Introduction

I've seen throughout the code-golf challenges several simple tasks involving JSON, such as interpreting JSON strings with RegExs,  and almost every other manipulation I could think of.

In a binding for [AppleScript](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-applescript) that I was using for a Node project, I noticed that objects would be returned in a strange way: there would be an array of properties in string form, instead of a JSON object being returned as expected. This is where the challenge comes in...

## Algorithm

1. Add `{` to beginning of the output string
2. Iterate over all entries, adding them to the output string, delimited by `,`
3. Add `}` to the end of the output string
4. Print out the output string

## Challenge

Make this strange return format usable. Convert an array of JSON `'key:value'`s (in string form) to a full JSON object string.

## Rules

- Any language that can do string manipulations allowed
- Must print out JSON string with surrounding curly braces `{}`, and double quotes `""` around string values **AND** all properties (`"property":"value"` or `"property":3.14`, etc.)
- Must return a valid, parseable JSON string
- Lowest byte count wins per language

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> ['prop1:"val1"', 'prop2:12', 'prop3:3.14', 'prop4:false']

Output:

> '{"prop1":"val1", "prop2":12, "prop3":3.14, "prop4":false}'

Comment: Welcome to ppcg.SE! Hope you have a great time here.

Comment: We don't put languages in boxes ^^

Comment: This challenge seems to be a [tag:code-golf] challenge, but it doesn't say in the post. Could you make it more clear?

Comment: This needs a tag for a challenge type.  I (like JungHwanMin) am assuming code golf but it really needs a tag.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site.  I'm voting to close this as unclear.  There are a couple of things I find unclear.  The first is that terms like "golfing" and "functional" languages are unclear, there are tons of edge cases.  I'd recommend getting rid of the bonuses altogether, which would make this challenge clearer and better.  It's also not clear to me exactly what the process is to change the strings to json is.  I think it ought to be defined much more concretely.

Comment: Your test case does not seem to match your description.  In the test case it seems that quotations were placed around attribute names, but that is not apparent in your specification.

Comment: Suggested test-cases: a key containing `:`, a value containing `:`, same for `,`.

Comment: Whats the actual input format? A list of strings? What characters can be in the string? ie, can the value or key contain a `:` or `"`?

Comment: The input format is either a string (or cstring, if unsupported) single-dimensional array. The input will only involve ASCII characters. The value can contain `"` (as `\"`) and `:`, but the property can't, as the property isn't a string in the input format (being in the format `'property:"value"'` for strings in an entry), so it wouldn't support string escape sequences.

Comment: Rule clarification please: must be input REALLY a JSON array of strings, or an array or array-like thing that is not necessarily a JSON array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 23 bytes

```
%0`\w+
"$&"
¶
,
.+
{$&}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X9UgIaZcm0tJRU2J69A2Lh0uPW2uahW12v//C4ryCwytlMoScwyVuEAcIytDIzDD2MpYz9AEzDSxSkvMKU4FAA) Explanation:

```
%0`\w+
"$&"
```

Quote all of the keys.

```
¶
,
```

Join the array elements together.

```
.+
{$&}
```

Wrap the result in brackets. This can also be done using the following code for the same byte count:

```
^
{
$
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 35 bytes

```javascript
a=>JSON.stringify(eval(`({${a}})`))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1s4r2N9Pr7ikKDMvPTOtUiO1LDFHI0GjWqU6sbZWM0FT8791cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmka0ekFRfoGhlRJQoaGSuo4CmG9kZWgEYxtbGesZmsB4JlZpiTnFqeqxmprW/wE) 43 bytes without builtins:

```javascript
a=>`{${a.map(s=>s.replace(/\w+/,`"$&"`))}}`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcfRCoMgFADQXxkSU1kzrJ4M@5Ft4MVdx4ZL0aiH6NsdDHo75wMLZJvecb5O4YnF6QJ6NFu1gfhCZFmPWSSMHiyy5r5emtqQ6kwM5/tuymDDlINH4cOLOXajMYUoFVnAS0Lr0/@tku3hTnVC9sd65cBnpA/Oh/ID)

Answer (score 1):

## C 108

**Thanks to Jonathan Frech this answer is now incredibly shorter**
**Thanks to @ceilingcat for some very nice pieces of golfing - now even shorter**

```
i;main(c,v)char**v;{for(;++i<c;printf("%c\"%s\":%s",!~-i*79+44,v[i],++*v))*(*v=index(i[v],58))=0;puts("}");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcfdCoIwGADQZ@kDYX9G00W15ZOoF2NlfWA6NhtB2Ksv8O4cVz6cyxnNy@JEnEjUPW1gLJnvMAdiOMerMz7gtAwECtdBETvQRQSx@5XITheulEgt9oJzlihlhKUGp9v9Q7BNvTieKW0Oxr@XSGAFatacsw@zlxqSHSVsqbSsNtS63ku1UenBjvH@Bw)

Comment: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##HczRDoIgFIDhZ@lsboDYQnEV5JOoF@wsk82UgXHT7NXJefd/Nz8WL8SU3sbOBHnkluJoPIttr7/D4olthLYP1M7beR0IZNhBFjpQWQB@@hU2z9n1nkvJY2t7vitSygiLTVg9jvugjT2vb5Q2F@0@ayCwAdVbSsn5xQkF0UwCDpRKlEdUqjoLeaRUg5nC8w8), keeping with using a `main` function.

Comment: [112 bytes](https://tio.run/##HczRDoIgFIDhZ@lsboDYQnEV5JOoF@wsk82UgXHT7NXJefd/Nz8WL8SU3sbOBHnkluJoPGNRf4fFE9sIbR@onbfzOhDIsIMsdKCyAPz0K2yes@s9l5LH1vZ8V6SUERabsHoc90Ebe17fKG0u2n3WQGADqreUkvOLEwqimQQcKJUoj6hUdRbySKkGM4XnHw).

Comment: @JonathanFrech I would never have come up with `!~-i++*79+44`  That's not just golfed better - it's a better answer.  Do you want to post it separately or shall i edit my answer?

Comment: Regarding the golf: `(i==1?"{":",")` <-> `(i==1?'{':',')` (when using `%c` instead of `%s`) <-> `(i==1?123:44)` (substituting actual ASCII values) <-> `44+(123-44)*(i==1)` <-> `44+79*(i==1)` <-> `44+79*!(i!=1)` <-> `44+79*!(i-1)` <-> `44+79*!~-i` <-> `!~-i*79+44`. The post-increment was used with regards to the entire program (not locally explainable). Regarding the posting: feel free to use the golfs in your post.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 79 bytes

Essentially [Neil's JS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169327/110802) solve.

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY2xCsIwEIb3PsVxOCRUilWngIO7TuJkRM6aSjSNMY2KlD57TSt60933c99fF2Soux0vqgiwJm2h6U6qhJKR2Kj7bhO8tuc9X2CDKWUVOXbIvHKGCrU0hqGUrxTHKHE0kYicZ9X1@8Mi5Sm22AH0xirKGflzLWDpPb3/agFbqwMsoEkgzpMMaOsePVnpOjB0/uZyITEmeewYw0CmIp/@9pmYZfn8d81FSaZWyAefiy3BWFaywcp72iZt0n0A)

```scala
def f(a:Seq[String])="{"+a.map(_.replaceAll("\\w+","\"$0\"")).mkString(",")+"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda x:"{%s}"%",".join('"'+a.replace(":",'":')for a in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcfRCsIgFADQX5EL4yqJ4NzThb5k9XArJcNU3IhF9O0Gwd7Oqe/1XrLr4XjqiZ@XG4uN4DMsXxhAg3mUmCUCHtg0XxNfvQQCjUCoQmmCRcxiU722mFcZ5Iy1lWoJXpwsoBb/j2TH3Y6csdO@iQKnxeNZqf4D)

-6 bytes thanks to ovs

Comment: 59 bytes using `a.replace(':','":')`

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 122 bytes

```lua
loadstring[[s="{"for i,v in ipairs(...)do x,y=v:match("(.-):(.+)")s=s.."\""..x.."\":"..y..","end return s:sub(1,-2).."}"]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCoMwEER/JezFXZouxPYU8EvaHtKqbSCNkqhUxG9Pg1R6e8MMM@NGk9oquc7UcQjWPy@XWMECbReElZOwXtje2BCRmanuxEfO1aTfZni8EJCPpJEPBBSryAxXAObPBjrTnElC42sRmmEMXkQdxzsqeSwpWyvcbqnPqwO2@L@A8Evnhm2WkIhSWoo@dL3SMBmnoJBi06VW5c4nfWJ13tVZt8bFpli/)

---

This is an anonymous function. It technically doesn't "print out JSON string [...]", but instead it returns this string, so that when calling it you could print. I did that because **I needed to first convert the input from string to an actual list**, and I did that on the argument of the function call.

**If this makes my answer invalid** I'll move the string to table (list) "parser" from the footer to the actual code. **But I don't think it should**, because the input shown as a table, so the code that takes a string and transforms it into a table shouldn't count.

Answer (score 0):

## POSIX sh (sed + [ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs makrj.sh](https://github.com/ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs/blob/master/makrj.sh)), 33 bytes

Assumes values may have colons but properties shall never have colons, spaces, tabs, or periods.

```sh
sed 's/\([^:]*\):/.\1 /'|makrj.sh
```

### Usage

Input via standard input. Each line represents each item of an array.

### Commented

```sh
# "prop:item"
sed 's/\([^:]*\):/.\1 /'|
# ".prop item" is JSONPath-value format
makrj.sh
# JSON object
```

### Example run on Termux

```bash
~ $ sh makrj.sh -h
Usage : makrj.sh [JSON_value_textfile]
Wed Sep 14 22:19:55 JST 2016
~ $ cat jsss;echo;cat jsss | sed 's/\([^:]*\):/.\1 /'|sh makrj.sh
prop1:"val1"
prop2:12
prop3:3.14
prop4:false

{
"prop1":"val1",
"prop2":12,
"prop3":3.14,
"prop4":false
}
~$
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 116 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s[]string)string{for i,l:=range s{s[i]=`"`+Replace(l,`:`,`":`,1)}
return"{"+Join(s,",")+"}"}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9BasMwEEX3OoWYlYTVgJIsisAXyKpkGwISRjJqZclIcjbCJ-nGFHqIHqW3qWrHm_nzP8y8mc-vPiw_o-o-VK_xoKxHdhhDzAcwQ4bvKZuX19-8ZylH6_sEyEy-w4ak232L6CbFhIgtc6KNyteFqaSbvbcSZHPVo1OdJo5JIZmEWjidUdR5ih4KNJdgPUkMGNAGZpif7PcV9X8ZobigJNqdWeQYw8gFPJTjIBle_VHw496fxOnAz7s7C6Nc0nJGb3U8u0pb95D6B6UUPYnLsukf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```ruby
->a{?{+a.map{_1.sub /\w+/,'"\&"'}*?,+?}}
```

Essentially Neil's JS solve.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3NXTtEqvtq7UT9XITC6rjDfWKS5MU9GPKtfV11JVi1JTUa7XsdbTta2uh6h0LSkuKFdKio9ULivILDK2UyhJzDJXUdRTAfCMrQyMY29jKWM_QBMYzsUpLzClOVY-NhRi0YAGEBgA)